# How to focus view(Navigator or Explorer) by keyboard in Eclipse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, navigation

I'm in edit space of Eclipse (in some java class)

So, how to focus(to switch) view(Navigator or Explorer) by keyboard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `<Ctrl><F7>`,`<Ctrl><Shift><F7>` to cycle through the different views.

Answer (score 5):

Via the menus: Window > Preferences, then General -> Keys
(or just Ctrl-Shift-L twice)

Then you can search in the `type filter text` field for "**view: navigator**" or **target id: navigator**

If there's not a key binding already, you can add one in the **Binding:** text field below.

Comment: thanks for help,didn't set binding in Eclipse before,really useful

Answer (score 1):

To navigate to the Java [Package Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fref-view-package-explorer.htm) specifically use the key binding <kbd>Alt+Shift+Q P</kbd>.

The key bindings to focus certain views in Eclipse all follow the pattern <kbd>Alt+Shift+Q <Letter></kbd> though not all views have a key binding of their own.

As an alternative there is the *Show In* menu. The key binding <kbd>Alt+ShiftW</kbd> opens a popup menu that lists all views in which the current selection/editor can be shown in. Navigation views like Package Explorer and [Project Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-27.htm) are always among the choices.